# return a file from src/main/resources using akka-http

Tags: scala, akka, spray, akka-http

I have a file abc.txt in my project's resources folder src/main/resources.
I have the following code snippet which is supposed to be serving the file.

```
get {
    path("hello") {
      complete {
        val s = Source.file(new File("src/main/resources/abc.txt"), 1024)
        s
      }
    }
```

I even tried the following

```
get {
path("hello") {
  complete {
    getFromFile("src/main/resources/abc.txt")
  }
}
```

In both the cases I get an error saying

> Expression of type routing.Route doesn't conform to expected Type toResponseMarshallable

My only requirement is that when I get this request I should be able to serve a file.
I did google for solution I couldn't find any.
Note: I am a Scala/Akka beginner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getFromFile` is a Directive, while `complete` expects a response.

Correct solution should be like:

```
val route: Route =
  path("hello") {
    getFromResource("abc.txt")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are working in two different worlds here. The `resources` are easier to get using the `calasspath`.

```
    val resourceStream: InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/"src/main/resources/abc.txt")
    val data: String = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(resourceStream).getLine.mkString
    data
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `getFromFile` was very close one, but it already defines an HTTP method, so you don't need to do it yourself. Something like this should work:

```
val route: Route =
  path("hello") {
    getFromFile("src/main/resources/abc.txt")
  }
```